# Select column of matrix based on a vetcor

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I don't think I described it clear in the title, so I just show the problem:
assdt is a vector:

```
assdt
 [1] 18 19  1  0 33 26  3  2 31 42 43 41 44
```

dt is a matrix:

```
dt 0 dt 1 dt 2 dt 3 dt 4 dt 5 dt 6 dt 7 dt 8 dt 9 dt 10 dt 11 dt 12 dt 13 dt 14 dt 15 dt 16 dt 17 dt 18 dt 19 dt 20
[1,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[2,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[3,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[4,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[5,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
[6,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"  
     dt 21 dt 22 dt 23 dt 24 dt 25 dt 26 dt 27 dt 28 dt 29 dt 30 dt 31 dt 32 dt 33 dt 34 dt 35 dt 36 dt 37 dt 38 dt 39
[1,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"  
[2,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"  
[3,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"  
[4,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"  
[5,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"  
[6,] "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"   "1"   "0"  
     dt 40
[1,] "1"  
[2,] "1"  
[3,] "1"  
[4,] "1"  
[5,] "1"  
[6,] "1"
```

I want to select the columns which are in `selectdt <- c(18,19,1,0,33,26,3,2,31,42,43,41,44)`. There is not columns 42,43,44 in dt, so just neglect them, I did `dt[,selectdt]`  there is an error `subscript out of bounds`. How to do it?

Comment: dt[,selectdt[selectdt<=ncol(dt)]], as per Roland's answer.

Comment: In case there could also be negative values in `selectdt` you could use `dt[, intersect(selectdt, seq_len(ncol(dt)))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mat <- as.matrix(mtcars)

cols <- c(1,5,20)
mat[, cols]
#Error in mat[, cols] : subscript out of bounds

mat[, cols[cols <= ncol(mat)]]
#                     mpg drat
#Mazda RX4           21.0 3.90
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 3.90
#...
```